# Australian retirement (super) for permanent residents leaving Australia permanently

Tags: australia, superannuation, permanent-resident

I am an Australian permanent resident.  I am considering leaving Australia permanently.  Under [Australian immigration laws](https://www.strategicmigration.com.au/permanent-visas/resident-return-visas), I would eventually no longer be an Australian permanent resident.  I am interested in knowing the rules regarding access to my superannuation funds:

For temporary residents the government [webpage](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Super/In-detail/Withdrawing-and-paying-tax/Super-information-for-temporary-residents-departing-Australia/) says:

> You can claim super benefits you accumulated while working in Australia if all of the following apply:
>
> you visited on a temporary visa (excluding visa subclasses 405 and 410)
>
> your visa has ceased to be in effect
>
> you have left Australia.

So that's not me - I'm not on a temporary visa.  For permanent residents it says

> you have the right to retire in Australia, so you cannot claim a DASP.

However, once I lose permanent residence, I no longer have the right to retire in Australia.  So this explanation no longer applies.  It is unclear what happens when an Australian permanent resident who is overseas is then no longer legally an Australian permanent resident.  What happens?

**edit** I have been told by a low-level person from my super company that once I am no longer a permanent resident they have to send my super to the Australian Tax Office and I can get it out as if I were a temporary resident.  I can find nothing that confirms or denies this.

Comment: Reading through the super rules, it looks to me like you would need to reach retirement age (65) and then you'd have access to your Super even if you're not formally retired in Australia.  It says:

You can access your super:

when you turn 65 (even if you haven’t retired), or
when you reach preservation age and retire, or
under the transition to retirement rules, while continuing to work.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the super rules, it looks to me like you would need to reach retirement age (65) and then you'd have access to your Super even if you're not formally retired in Australia.

Here:
https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Super/Accessing-your-super/

It says:

> You can access your super:
>
> *when you turn 65 (even if you haven’t retired)*, or
>   when you reach preservation age and retire, or
>   under the transition to retirement rules, while continuing to work.